# Can't install my app on IPAD (freeze at "installing")

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, flash

I've created an AS3 app with Adobe Flash CC. I'm using AIR 3.9. 
It works great on android devices but when I've created an .ipa file and transfer it to my Ipad (with IO7), my app is visible but freeze on "installing" (nothing's happening.)

Do you know what could be the problem ?

Thank you very much for your answers,

**EDIT : I'm using the ALPACA Source engine ([Infos Here)](http://www.alpacaengine.com/docs)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when an improper certificate and/or mobile provisioning file was used to compile the app (and is a known bug on iOS 7. It never gives an error message and just tries to keep installing the app).

You need to make sure the following are true:

- The app was compiled with either a development or distribution certificate made using Apple's developer portal. It **must** come from that portal. I have never seen a working way to do it without a certificate generated there and I do not believe it is possible.
- The mobile provisioning file used matches the certificate. A developer certificate is used for a development provisioning profile and a distribution certificate is used for an ad hoc or app store provisioning file.
- Again, make sure the provisioning profile comes from Apple's developer portal. This one is a little more flexible and I believe it can be faked by other sources, but why bother?
- The provisioning profile **must** include your device's UDID. This is the only way an app can be installed on your device without it coming from the app store
- You must use either a development (if your device is set up for development) or ad hoc provisioning profile. An App Store provisioning profile will fail to install.

Answer (score 0):

It only worked for me when i created ad-hoc provisioning profile and used in the intellij project settings