# ERROR ITMS-9000: Invalid Code Signing

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex-mobile, application-loader

For an Adobe AIR app (which is published since over a year in Apple App Store) I'm trying to submit an update using Application Loader, but get the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Code Signing. The executable
>   'Payload/XXX.app/XXX' must be signed with the certificate that is
>   contained in the provisioning profile." at
>   SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

[image: application loader screenshot]

The app has been created with Flash Builder 4.7 and Apache Flex 4.11.0 and AIR 4.0:

[image: apache flex installer]

The app compiles and runs at my test device (iPhone 5c) just fine.

Why is it rejected by the Application Loader?

It could be something minor, like a missing icon or splash image...

Of course I have tried the obvious several times and revoked/created new certifcates and created new distribution provisioning profiles for the App Store.

Below is the excerpt from my XXX-app.xml:

```
<autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
<visible>true</visible>
<softKeyboardBehavior>none</softKeyboardBehavior>

<icon>
        <image16x16>assets/icons/icon-16x16.png</image16x16>
        <image29x29>assets/icons/icon-29x29.png</image29x29>
        <image32x32>assets/icons/icon-32x32.png</image32x32>
        <image36x36>assets/icons/icon-36x36.png</image36x36>
        <image48x48>assets/icons/icon-48x48.png</image48x48>
        <image57x57>assets/icons/icon-57x57.png</image57x57>
        <image72x72>assets/icons/icon-72x72.png</image72x72>
        <image114x114>assets/icons/icon-114x114.png</image114x114>
        <image128x128>assets/icons/icon-128x128.png</image128x128>
        <image512x512>assets/icons/icon-512x512.png</image512x512>

        <image50x50>assets/icons/icon-50x50.png</image50x50>
        <image58x58>assets/icons/icon-58x58.png</image58x58>
        <image76x76>assets/icons/icon-76x76.png</image76x76>
        <image100x100>assets/icons/icon-100x100.png</image100x100>
        <image120x120>assets/icons/icon-120x120.png</image120x120>
        <image144x144>assets/icons/icon-144x144.png</image144x144>
        <image152x152>assets/icons/icon-152x152.png</image152x152>
        <image1024x1024>assets/icons/icon-1024x1024.png</image1024x1024>
</icon>

<iPhone>
<InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
                <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
                <array>
                        <string>1</string>
                        <string>2</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
                <false/>
        ]]></InfoAdditions>
<requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>

<extensions>
        <extensionID>com.adobe.Vibration</extensionID>
        <extensionID>com.adobe.ane.gameCenter</extensionID>
    </extensions>
</application>
```

The splash images included in the .ipa file are:

```
Default-568h@2x.png
Default-Landscape.png
Default-Landscape@2x.png
Default-Portrait.png
Default-Portrait@2x.png
Default.png
Default@2x.png
```

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421627/cant-install-my-app-on-ipad-freeze-at-installing/20428354#20428354). Additionally, make sure the certificate used to build matches the certificate you designated in the developer portal and make sure you follow Adobe's instruction when converting the `.cer` file to a `.p12` file

Comment: Are you sure your answer applies to Adobe AIR apps? The error messages can be misleading there (see the recent problems with AIR 3.9 submissions rejected by App Store). I did follow the Adobe's instructions, even several times.

Comment: Yes. I am an AIR dev, pretty sure my instructions are right. The error messages are correct from Apple. Figuring out how to fix it in AIR is usually the issue. In this case, you have a certificate issue and nothing more. If you were missing an icon, Apple would tell you. If you weren't using the latest version of AIR 4.0 (released last week), Apple would tell you it needs to be built with Xcode 5. This error means you aren't using the correct certificate and/or provisioning profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need you use the AIR 4.0 beta (selectable form the installer AIR menu).

One of the fixed issues is:
Bug 3686074: [APPLE][XCODE5] New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 from Feb1

Comment: Using Flex 4.11.0 and AIR 13.0beta has helped, thank you