# ERROR ITMS-9000: “No architectures in the binary"

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.7

I am getting an error trying to upload an app to the iOS store.

The application was developed using FlashBuilder 4.7 and Flex 13.0.

ERROR ITMS-9000: “No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable.” At SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

Does anyone have any ideas as to what this error is?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: May be a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020535/error-itms-9000-invalid-code-signing/22030023#22030023 Are you using the latest version of AIR from Adobe labs?

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix your application.xml:

```
    <iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[...
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
]]></InfoAdditions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of my question after lots of try. After updating an air sdk still I got this issue.

Solution of this issue is simple.

We don't need to use any digit in app Id.

for example:

App was not submitteds app id contains digit like com.adobe.sample.7th

then I created new app having app id like com.adobe.sample.seventh and I was able to submit this app to store.