# I can't see my app on my iPad

Tags: ipad, adobe-indesign

I have created an app using Indesign CC and gone through everything to downloaded the .ipa file and put it in my iTunes folder. But I can't get it on my iPad. I have synced and it hasn't shown up. I have updated to iOS 7.1 and it still doesn't show up?

this is the only thing i could find about it [Can't install my app on IPAD (freeze at "installing")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421627/cant-install-my-app-on-ipa) d-freeze-at-installing

But I have used the keychain to check that my certificates are OK and they both say they are valid. do i need to do them again just to incase?

HELP PLEASE this deadline is TIGHT!

Comment: `HELP PLEASE this deadline is TIGHT!` will lower your chances of getting the question answered.

Comment: Sorry i didnt know what else to say as we litterally need this for tomorrow. Are you able to help?